# Text line height inconsistency in puppeteer. Ideas how to fix?

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I've got quite a strange issue. I have a text element that has quite a large font-size (155px).
Now, i've set the line-height to 0.9 in order to "minimize" the dead space on above and below the text. This is what it looks currently:
[Large Font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00ACj.png)

As you can see, the "dead space" above the text is ever so slightly larger than below.
However, the page this text resides on is intentend to be printed to PDF using puppeteer. When i open the page through the puppeteer debugger and inspect the element, it looks like this:
[Large Font on puppeteer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeyxF.png)

Here is my css for the text in question:

```css
  .text {
    font-size: 155px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0.9;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<p class="text">1234</p>
```

Does anyone know how i could fix this? Is there maybe a way to vertically align the text in "itself"?

Thanks

Edit:

It seems that the custom font i'm using is responsible for this inconsistency. Changing the font to Arial fixes the issue and the alignment is identical.

Comment: vertical-align: middle; maybe?

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work.
I've done some more testing and it seems that somehow the custom Font is the issue. Changing the Font to Arial for example, fixes the issue and the alignment is identical in Chrome & puppeteer.